# APK file is generating without "src" code

Tags: android

When I try to generate an apk file from android studio "src" code in there in apk file. I opened apk using "winrar" but, there is no src folder in it.

What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source code is converted into dex file. You will file .dex file in the extracted folder.

When you build APK in the android studio. It converts your source code into java ByteCode(.class file) and then again process all class file into single/multiple Dex file(.dex) based on method count.

Check this image for more information:
[image]

Image Reference [link](https://www.javatpoint.com/images/androidimages/flow.jpg).

Comment: @Maharsh you can learn more about How Android Apps are Built and Run from here https://github.com/dogriffiths/HeadFirstAndroid/wiki/How-Android-Apps-are-Built-and-Run.

Answer (score 1):

The src folder is your source code.

No Java or Android application actually runs your source code, rather all Java files are compiled to class files and relocated to the classpath of a JAR, or APK or AAR for Android. Typically there are folders for each package, then class files under that